# How to make SQL query that spots missing value from 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

I am having trouble making a sql query.
here is the table that I have.

```
/* fruit.csv */
code,status,fruit
AAA,active,Apple
ABA,inactive,Banana
BAB,active,Apple
CAA,active,Orange
CBA,active,Apple
BBA,active,Strawberry

/* color.csv */
code,color
AAA,orange
AAA,red
AAA,blue
BAB,blue
BAB,orange
CAA,red
CAA,yellow
CAA,orange
CAA,blue
CBA,red
CBA,yellow
CBA,green
BBA,red
```

and what I need is

```
code,fruit,missingColor
BAB,Apple,red
```

And here is what I want to filter with

1. from fruit, the get only one that is active and either apple or strawberry
2. compare with color.csv and if the current code has the color of red as a value then that is valid. otherwise, it is invalid. and return the code, what fruit it is and the missing color which is red.

basically, I have to combine the following 2 queries.

```
select f.code from fruit f where f.status = 'active' and f.fruit = 'Apple' or f.fruit = 'Strawberry';
select c.code from color c where c.color = 'red';
```

But I am stuck and not sure how to combine it correctly, I used group by and distinct. but not sure if I am supposed to use them to get what I need.
If it is just simple one query, then I know when to use group by or distinct, but when it gets difficult, I am not sure what to use.
Can someone help me get this right?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, note that Oracle and MySQL are different DBMS and Oracle tag is about Oracle DB.

Comment: thank you. I thought my question would be very basic and does not matter what db is used. I will specify it next time

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like filtering.  One way is:

```
select f.*
from fruit f
where f.status = 'active' and
      f.fruit in ('apple', 'strawberry') and
      not exists (select 1
                  from color c
                  where c.code = f.code and c.color = 'red'
                 );
```

Comment: i see. i did not think about making a query in that way. thanks